# UILabel showing NSAttributedString with large images going out of bounds

Tags: html, ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a `UILabel` that displays HTML text. The raw HTML text is first converted to `NSAttributedString` which is then displayed in the `UILabel`.

The problem I'm facing is that the large size images in the HTML go outside the bounds of `UILabel`. The `<img>` objects in HTML should scale-to-fit inside the `UILabel` bounds, but they do not.

How can I fix this?

JS Fiddle Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/n4xr3kdd/1/

**Edit (2015-12-15):**

I've tried to wrap the HTML text in following wrapper code and it works:

```
<style>.img_wrapper img {width:100%;}</style><div class="img_wrapper" style="width: 250px;">[INSERT_HTML_TEXT_HERE]</div>
```

But, it scales the images to fix 250px width, as a result showing extra white space on the right hand side. I want the images to rescale/resize dynamically based on the `width` of the `UILabel` (which is different on different devices and orientations).

Comment: Tried setting `clipsToBounds` to `YES?`

Comment: It's already doing that, and I don't want that.

Comment: @Mustafa I meet the same issue, DO you have fixed it?

Comment: Yes, I've given my solution as an Edit. I wrapped the HTML text.